# convert SharedArrayBuffer to normal ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, canvas, arraybuffer, imagedata, sharedarraybuffer

I am trying to create a new `ImageData` from a `Uint8ClampedArray` based on a `SharedArrayBuffer`, since the `ImageData` constructor doesnt accept a `Uint8ClampedArray` based on a `SharedArrayBuffer` I have to convert it to a normal `ArrayBuffer` somehow.

Any Ideas how I can convert the `SharedArrayBuffer` to a normal `ArrayBuffer` or how I could create `ImageData` with a `SharedArrayBuffer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to copy that data in its own buffer that the context will own entirely.

You can do so by just calling `.slice()` on the Uint8ClampedArray you have from the SAB:

```js
const sab = new SharedArrayBuffer( 50 * 50 * 4 );
const arr = new Uint8ClampedArray( sab );
const img = new ImageData( arr.slice(), 50, 50 );
```

Or if you are going to draw the content of this SAB multiple times, then create once a fixed ArrayBuffer and fill it with the SAB's content:

```js
const sab = new SharedArrayBuffer( 50 * 50 * 4 );
const sab_view = new Uint8ClampedArray( sab );

const ab = new ArrayBuffer(sab.byteLength);
const arr = new Uint8ClampedArray( ab );
const img = new ImageData( arr, 50, 50 );
// later when sab has new content being set
arr.set(sab_view, 0);
```

#### **[Live example](https://putimagedata-sharedarraybuffer.glitch.me/)** <sub>([source](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/putimagedata-sharedarraybuffer?path=public%2Fscript.js%3A22%3A34))</sub>

*(outsourced because SharedArrayBuffer requires COOP, that StackSnippet is not gonna give us...).*

Comment: This is painfully slow. Is there a reason why it is not allowed to use SharedArrayBuffer directly to ImageData?